# CSS: fade out picture and fade in text

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make circular buttons at the bottom of my webpage to link to different parts of the site. The buttons have images, and when they are hovered over I want to image to fade and a piece of text to appear. I have had considerable difficulty with this and haven't found anything online.

I have had several close solutions, but none quite work as well as I want them to. I have tried nesting the text inside of the div with the image, but then the text fades to the same opacity as the button.  I had another solution where I got the text and image to fade out/in correctly, but the border of where the fade was triggered was way off (ie the image would fade when the mouse was nowhere near the button.

Below is the code for my current attempt. My strategy here has been to trigger both the image and text fades with a hover over the image so the boarders that trigger the fade are correct. The problem is that if I nest the text in the image I get the image fade, and if I don't nest it the I can't get the hover even to trigger. Below is my current code.

HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
 <div class="circular_one">
  <h2 class="abt_one" id="abt_one">About</h2>
   <div class="img_one" id="img_one"></div>
 </div> 
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.img_one {  
    margin-left: auto;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    border-radius: 150px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 150px;
    -moz-border-radius: 150px;
    background: url('IMG_2612.jpg') no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);

}

.img_one:hover {    
    margin-left: auto;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    opacity: 0.5;
    transition: all 0.75s ease-in-out;
    border-radius: 150px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 150px;
    -moz-border-radius: 150px;
    background-image: url('IMG_2612.jpg') no-repeat;
    background-color: #483D8B;
    background-size: cover;
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);

}

#abt_one {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-right: 110px;
    padding-left: 90px;
    padding-bottom: 110px;
    font-size: 35px;
    position: absolute;

}

#img_one:hover + #abt_one {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding-top: 110px;
    padding-right: 110px;
    padding-left: 90px;
    padding-bottom: 110px;
    transition: all 0.75s ease-in-out;
    font-size: 5px;
    position: absolute;

}
```

Comment: You've gotten a significant amount of answers, did none of these work for you?

Answer (score 0):

[JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/rofipanuso/2/edit)

you should use this structure :

```
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="circular_one">
     <div class="img_one" id="img_one"> 
       <h2 class="abt_one" id="abt_one">About</h2>     
       </div>
    </div>  
  </div>
```

as you see, the **#abt_one** is a child of **#img_one**. and change the css, you will achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0):

This is much easier done using jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $('#img_one').hover(function() { 
    $('#abt_one').slideDown(350); 
}, function() { 
    $('#abt_one').fadeOut(3); 
    });
});
```

You can specify the speeds for `slideDown()` and `fadeOut()` by placing a number within the brackets. The numbers represent milliseconds.

Here's a fiddle...http://jsfiddle.net/4z2zq/350/

You can even add a few more effects to make the transition smoother:

```
$(function() {
    $('#img_one').hover(function() { 
    $('#abt_one').slideDown(350)
    .css('opacity', 0)
    .animate({ opacity: 1 },
    { queue: false, duration: 'slow' });
}, function() { 
    $('#abt_one').fadeOut(3); 
    });
});
```

Here's the second fiddle...http://jsfiddle.net/4z2zq/351/

Using jQuery will allow you to remove a significant amount of code from your CSS file.

Answer (score 0):

For animations using CSS I recommend using [animate.css](http://daneden.github.io/animate.css/).

Very simple to use, just add this snippet to your HT

```
<script>
   $('.CLASSNAME').addClass('animated fadeIn');
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you must use CSS, the following will work...http://jsfiddle.net/9rCQv/98/

I changed your html so that `h2` is inside the `img_one` div, this is needed for the hover to affect `h2` as well. In other words, I made `h2` a child element of `img_one` :

```
<div class="col-md-4">
 <div class="circular_one">
   <div class="img_one" id="img_one">
    <h2 class="abt_one" id="abt_one">About</h2>
   </div>
 </div> 
</div>
```

Then I changed your CSS to the following:

```
#abt_one {
    visibility: hidden;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-right: 110px;
    padding-left: 90px;
    padding-bottom: 110px;
    font-size: 35px;
    position: absolute;
    opacity 1s;   
    opacity: 0;
}

#img_one:hover #abt_one {
    visibility:visible;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding-top: 150px;
    padding-right: 110px;
    padding-left: 90px;
    padding-bottom: 110px;
    transition: all 0.75s ease-in;
    font-size: 35px;
    position: absolute; 
    opacity:1;
}
```

The main things I changed in your CSS were the `visibility` and `opacity` properties. I made it transition smoothly into view by combining `opacity` with `transition`.